Homogeneous Lagrangian in covariant Lagrangian formulations
I have a question in Chapter $7.10$ of Goldstein et. al.'s classical mechanics (3rd edition). Specifically, on page 320 about the discussion of covariant Lagrangian formulations.
First, they introduce a parameter $\theta$ to mark the system-point's travel through space, and
$$
\frac{d x^i}{d t}=\frac{d x^i}{d \theta} \frac{d \theta}{d t}=c \frac{x^{\prime i}}{x^{\prime 0}} , \tag{7.158}
$$
where $x^0=ct$ and $x^{\prime i}=dx^i/d\theta$. Hence, the action integral is transformed as
$$
I=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} L\left(x^j, t, \dot{x}^j\right) d t=\frac{1}{c} \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} L\left(x^j, c \frac{x^{\prime j}}{x^{\prime 0}}\right) x^{\prime 0} d \theta .
$$
Then, a suitable choice of Lorentz invariant Lagrangian $\Lambda$ is defined as
$$
\Lambda\left(x^\mu, x^{\prime \mu}\right)=\frac{x^{\prime \phi}}{c} L\left(x^\mu, c \frac{x^{\prime j}}{x^{\prime 0}}\right) . \tag{7.159}
$$
They mentioned that the new Lagrangian $\Lambda$ is a homogeneous function of the generalized velocities in the first degree:
$$
\Lambda\left(x^\mu, a x^{\prime \mu}\right)=a \Lambda\left(x^\mu, x^{\prime \mu}\right) . \tag{7.160}
$$
My question is: How to understand Eq.($7.160$) and how to prove this? I can see this from the transformation $c\rightarrow c a$. However, $c$ is the speed of light, and the four velocity $u_\nu$ relation, $u_\nu u^\nu=c^2$ must be satisfied.

Why index $\phi$ instead of $0$? Which printing? Which year?

@Qmechanic I also think the index should be $0$ instead of $\phi$. In third edition, @ 2002. Reprint in 2020.
